# Tomar status de http response angular

Tags: angular

Buen dia amigos, estuve investigando y no pude conseguir una manera de tomar el status de la response de mi api, el status de "ok" es el status 200, si es diferente a ello mostrar el error que aparece en el array del http response tal como se aparece en la captura

[image: Api Response]

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';
import { LoginInt } from 'src/app/Interfaces/login.interfaces';
import { ResponseLInt } from 'src/app/Interfaces/responseL.interface';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  FLogin: FormGroup = this.fb.group({ 

email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]]
  }
    )

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private api:LoginService) { }


  campoValido (campo: string){

    return this.FLogin.controls[campo].errors && this.FLogin.controls[campo].touched

  }


  guardar(form:LoginInt){

    this.api.LoginPass(form).subscribe(data =>{
      console.log(data);            
      ;}
      },

      
      )

    

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

aca esta el servicio

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { LoginInt } from '../../../Interfaces/login.interfaces';
import { ResponseLInt } from '../../../Interfaces/responseL.interface';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";




@Injectable({

providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService{

    url: string='https://apitest.e-bango.com';


    constructor(private http:HttpClient){}


    LoginPass(form:LoginInt):Observable<ResponseLInt>{
        
        let direccion = this.url + "/api/auth/login"
        
        return this.http.post<ResponseLInt>(direccion,form)
    }
}
```

Me podrian ayudar con esto? que tendria que poner para obtener el status del HttpErrorResponse, mis disculpas si la pregunta es muy basica pero en serio estoy atorado luego de horas de buscarlo. Gracias por adelantado

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que tienes que hacer es pasar el callback para manejar los errores

```
this.api.LoginPass(form).subscribe(

    (data) => {
      console.log(data);            
    },

    (error) => {
      console.log(error);            
    }
)
```